# How to emulate the latest versions of Internet Exporer Mobile

Tags: html, testing, mobile-website

I need to test a mobile website using the latest version of IE Mobile, but i don't want to install the windows phone emulator because i think it's too heavy for my PC and i don't want to install a whole OS only to view some web pages.
I am looking for a browser emulator or a plugin if IE desktop.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution i found at the moment is to change User Agent String on IE10.

- Press F12
- Click on "Tools"
- Click on "Change user Agent String"
- Select IE10 for Windows Phone 8